# Unknown column error but I have this column in phpmyadmin. but others tools can execute without error

Tags: mysql, sql

Local server this query run smooth. But when I run this hosting server i get this error

> #1054 - Unknown column 'orders.id' in 'order clause'

### EDIT

> This is not my server problem. this is phpmyadmin unexpected problem.
>   I discover this when I run this same query on mysql workbench. mysql
>   workbench return exact result

Here is my query. *Note that I have `orders.id` column*

```
SELECT * FROM orders ord1
join (select * from orders where orders.is_visible=1) ord2
on ord1.id=ord2.id
where ord1.company_id is not null
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the query with the error? There is no `order by` clause.

Comment: There's no mention of `orders.id` anywhere in that query, it can't be the one causing this error.

Comment: A little over-confident perhaps?

Comment: I think you have missed some part of the actual query?

Comment: no, I have check again. I'm sure

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a sqlfiddle?

Comment: @Barmar in my `on` clause check `ord1.id=ord2.id` ord1 and ord2 are alias of orders table.

Comment: The error message doesn't say `ord1.id` or `ord2.id`, it tsays `orders.id`. It also says that the problem is in the `order clause`, not the `on` clause.

Comment: Just a thought... Do you have a TRIGGER?

Comment: the problem would be with table alias may be, @imran may be try accessing id columns with original table name instead of alias names

Comment: No, I have not trigger

Comment: anyway, why you need to join the table? just 1 simple query will do right ?SELECT * FROM orders where is_visible=1 and company_id is not null

Comment: @Barmar I cant access sqlfiddle. my server version is 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using phpMyAdmin by any chance? My understanding is that phpMyAdmin adds an `order by` clause. If you explicitly select the columns you actually need (rather then `*`) it should fix the problem.

Comment: yes. you are right I edit my question when I see that

Answer (score 0):

The same result you are trying to achieve can be obtained by doing the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    orders 
WHERE
    company_id IS NOT NULL
    AND is_visible = 1
```

Try to run this query which basically does the exact same, however more efficiently. You do not need to join a table to itself in order to apply multiple conditions.

Comment: `company_id IS NOT NULL
    AND is_visible = 1 ` check both . But I need orders which have company_id null but is_visible =1 separately

Comment: What happens when you select the explicit columns you need from `ord2` and give them aliases?

Comment: @imran if that's the case I don't think your originally query would work. The query you gave and the one here will return the same results, to the best of my knowledge. Try and recreate the error you're having in SQL Fiddle, and/or post some sample data and expected results to your question.